# Converting 3x to 1x Drivetrain

Tags: crankset, cassette, drivetrain

I have a new crankset ([link](http://www.jensonusa.com/!u8piKNIJIOi6iTM8Skhlow!/Race-Face-Atlas-6873mm-Crankset)) on the way as well as a chain guide/bash combo from OneUp. I am getting a 36T narrow-wide chainring also.

The bike I'm working on has a SRAM 3x9 drivetrain with 11-34 cassette. What else, if anything, do I need to convert it to 1x9 (other than putting the new crankset on and removing the unnecessary front der & shifter)?

Is it correct that Shimano 11sp cassettes fit on 8/9/10sp freehub, so I could in theory change it to a 10sp or 11sp cassette? I'm not planning on doing that ATM but just in case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General consensus is that a 'clutched' rear derailleur is also a key component to a good/successful 1x setup. These derailleurs provide a tighter 'pull' on the chain and help keep it from hopping off the chainring on rough terrain.

For cassette/freehub compatibility, read the discussion that occurred here: 
https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/28908/30533 ...

> *Shimano/SRAM 11 speed cassettes are wider than 8/9/10 speed ones. So yes, you need a new, wider freehub body, unless your old one was not very old and used a spacer to fit a 10-speed cassette.*

Comment: OK, so to clarify I could use a 1x10 on the current freehub, but I *might* need a different freehub if I ever wanted to go 1x11 (I don't intend to). Also, is clutched derailleur necessary if running a narrow-wide chainring **and** a chain guide? I've seen some discussions about that and from what I've read, seems unnecessary in that case.

Comment: Yes - you would need a different freehub body for an 11 speed cassette. 

I suppose it's a matter of preference, how much 'protection' a given rider wants against chain issues. Your chain guide will probably alleviate 99% of issues. A clutched derailleur might help prevent the (remote) possibility of your chain slapping off of the lower part of your chainring, just before you ratchet/back-pedal on a descent (unlikely, but not impossible).

Comment: As SRAM has better/stronger tension than shimano, it is not neccessary to get a clutch mech. BTW Sram does not have any clutch mech.

I am using saint 9 speed without any clutch, what I did I just cut short the chain and installed a cheap lower guide to prevent the slap on my chain ring.